# GCS cloud storage standard pricing

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using GCS standard bucket. If I am writing 100 GB of data from multiple processes and deleting after fetching it for once, how does the storage cost work ? Let's say I have 5 processes that writes 100 GB each and deletes them after using the data once. At a given point in time , max bucket size will be 250 for 30 mins in 24 hours.  How is the pricing work in this situation ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [pricing tables](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#price-tables), it looks like you would just get charged for:

- operations (i.e. `storage.bucklet.list`, etc.), which would be depend on how many operations your processes are calling for that 100GB of data
- any inter-region replication (unless you have just a regional bucket, replication costs in dual/multi-region buckets would be @ $0.02/GB, so $100GB would cost you $2)
- egress costs (which varies depending on your use case and where it egresses to)

Answer (score 1):

For a standard bucket, its prorated. So if we have data of 100GB for 1 hour. We will be charged 100 * 0.026 * 1/960. Refer to https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-examples#prorate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).